# 12 In 24 working hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

[image]

[image]

How do I calculate the number of hours worked within 24 hours?

If the shift starts at 6 AM and finishes at 2 PM with a half an hour break, and the shift the following day starts at 4 AM and finishes at 12 PM with a half an hour break, how many hours in 24 hours has that person worked, the 24 hour period starts at 6 AM which is the start of the first shift.

My formula doesn't seem to be accurate, I think I may be missing something.

```
=SUM((start break-start shift)+(finish break-finish shift)+(start break second shifts-start second shift)+(finish second shift-finish break second shift))
```

Comment: Why not just calculate duration of work and substract the duration of breaks? So it would be `(End Shift-Start Shift)-(End Break-Start Break)`?

Comment: The issue is calculating the number of hours worked from the start of the first shift till 24 hours later. so if a shift starts at 7am, how many hours has this person worked till 7am the next day

Comment: How is your data laid out?

Comment: this is the formula =SUM((C2-B2)+(D2-E2)+(G2-F2)+(I2-H2))

Comment: I think I am missing something to make it calculate a specific 24 hour period, starting at B2 which is the start of the first shift. Is there anything that I can add or maybe change in the formula to make it calculate the number of work hours in a 24 hour period starting at B2 ?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show a representative data example (as a text table or screenshot)

Comment: Thank you, I just added 2 screenshots in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing part is to test for whether or not 2nd shift started earlier than 1st shift.  Using an =IF() to see if the time in F is less than the time in B works, but you can simplify it by using a =MAX().

Try one of these three options, depending on whether your 24 hour period starts with 1st or 2nd shift and whether or not your times also include dates:

Here's the data:
[image]

Here I revealed the formulas:
[image]

Also, it doesn't affect the outcome, but in your formula above, you don't need the =SUM() in addition to the plusses and minuses.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :

`1st_break_start - 1st_start + 1st_end - 1st_break_end + if(2nd_start > 1st_start + 1, min(2nd_break_start, 1st_start +1)-2nd_start) + if(2nd_break_end > 1st_start +1,min(2nd_end,1st_start+1)-2nd_break_end)`